# run setuid as www-data in python

Tags: python, linux, apache, setuid

I have a python script running as `www-data` but I would like it to have separate `r/w/e` permissions to the rest of the scripts. So I created a user to use however can't get the script to run as that user (it's a `cgi` script and I want all but this one running as `www-data`). Is there anyway I can use `os.setuid()` to demote myself to this user?. It seems to work the other way around but not from `www-data` to new user

Comment: can you use `chmod` to modify this specific script permissions?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori yes. I tried setting the setuid bit however apparently I would need to do it to the interpreter, not the script